# How can I deque UICollectionViewCells before needed, as first time deque is laggy

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

OK, I am implementing a calendar that pretty much looks like Apple's Calendar app. 
I have many types of cells in my `UICollectionView`. 
I have cells for vertical lines, cells for horizontal lines, a cell for now line, and for events.

Whenever I scroll, and a cell appears for the first time, there is a little glitch, lag, delay, name it however.

As a POC, I created this test case:
Create 2 days. One has 5 events from 00:00 to 05:00, and 5 events from 17:00 to 22:00. The second day has only 5 events from 17:00 to 22:00.
The first day, which has also the morning events, doesn't lag when scrolling to the 17:00-22:00 events. The second one DOES.

PLUS, there is no lag at all in the line cells, as they are presented in every frame of the collectionView.

This leads me to the question - I want to have the cells deque'd before scrolling - so I know that cells that are NOT in the screen (but will be once the users scrolls) are deque'd in an amount that will be efficient for the collectionView to reuse them once the user scrolls.

Naive approach which I am not sure about will be something like this:

in `ViewDidLoad()` to run something like this:

```
(0...10).forEach { num in
    calendarCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "UserEventCollectionViewCell", for: IndexPath(item: num, section: 3)) //3 is my events section
}
```

this leads to a crash:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xae106)
```

How can I achieve this? Or is there any better approach?

**Some screenies:**

In the screen shots - the area with the lines and hours is a contained VC, which is the relevant for the question (under the label "monday, ...")

[image: this area doesn't lag]

[image: this area lags]

Comment: There is not a simple answer to this. First I'd try to identify what causes the lag. You can find a few tips in these articles https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/perfect-smooth-scrolling-in-uitableviews-fd609d5275a5, https://medium.com/capital-one-developers/smooth-scrolling-in-uitableview-and-uicollectionview-a012045d77f.

Comment: Thanks for those. The difference here is that my scrolling is smooth after the first time the nib of a certain cell was dequed. It only lags when loading a nib that wasn't displayed yet

Comment: @MartinPrusa Could you please explain what you mean (viewDidAppear)? Implement calendarCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell like I posted in the question?

Comment: I'd try to implement `calendarCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell` in `viewDidAppear` that could eliminate the `BAD_ACCESS`, but if you want smart asynchronously pre-rendered layout you'll need something like this http://texturegroup.org/docs/intelligent-preloading.html

Comment: I meant to try to put the `dequeueReusableCell` in `viewDidAppear`, but that won't be a solution. If it lags on deque, it means that your layout is somehow complicated, or reuse (`prepareForReuse`) is not handled correctly. Try to eliminate a few parts of the cell to determine what's causing the problem.

Comment: Well I should of probably stated this in the question, but I reproduced the exact same issue with a new cell that has no inner views, and no functionality..

Comment: Yeah maybe. If it lags this way it means somewhere above is the issue, maybe your collection is inside of some other collection, I am not sure.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering maybe you have a tableView inside a collectionViewCell? Maybe 2 or 3 collectionViews on the same ViewController? Maybe paste a piece of code here or a screenshot with your collectionView in Simulator?

Comment: I have 5 - 6 collectionViews. Most of them show 4 - 5 cells all together, so I cannot believe that is a source to the problem. There are no embedded collectionViews/tableViews. Only one of the collectionViews show multiple Item types. I will post a screen shot

Comment: @Starsky added the screen shots.

Comment: I really did every possible optimisation. I am not doing anything on the main thread except basic UI things like putting label text and colours.

Comment: You have 5-6 collectionViews on this ViewController? or you have 5-6 collectionViewCells?? If it is the first option, then this is why you're experiencing lags ;)

Comment: @Starsky I have 5 - 6 collectionViews and each one has 4 -5 cells at the same time. I don't see any reason for this to cause a lag, and it doesn't. There are no lags except for the first time I am showing a cell that was not initially in the screen. Plus, the question asks how to invoke to deque some cells even though they are not presenting yet, knowing that they will be presented. I am not asking why I am lagging..

Comment: Alright. I can't help you exactly with you exact question, although you are wrong regarding that 5-6 colectionViews are not causing the lag. Each collectionView calls several times the function cellForRowAt when you scroll, thus causing the lags. Better have 1 collectionView with different sections and with different customCells for each section. Good luck!

Comment: OK I confused you! I am using sections in the collectionView inside the container. .. the other collectionViews are not in the container

Comment: Inside contained VC there is just 1 collectionView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - this is pretty crazy. We found that the reason for our lags was solely the fact that we had too many print outs to the console. We removed them and everything is smooth now.
This is not a direct answer to my question, but it makes me understand - when you think you need to pre load nib files to boost smoothness - something else in your implementation is the reason for the lags and you should find it instead of hacking through it.